# How to make the object props name and method correspond to each other in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> =
  ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;

type ELE = ArrayElement<typeof KeyToVal>;
```

The ELE type like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRlmX.png)

How to changed to

```
type Result = {
  setTitle: () => number;
  getName: (name: '123') => "123";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a type that looks like this:

```
type ELE = {
  readonly name: "setTitle"
  readonly method: () => number
} | {
  readonly name: "getName"
  readonly method: (name: "123") => "123"
}
```

You can get the desired result by mapping over the union.

```
type Result = {
  [E in ELE as E["name"]]: E["method"]
}

// type Result = {
//     setTitle: () => number;
//     getName: (name: "123") => "123";
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=5&pln=16&pc=1#code/FAguE8AcFMAIFEAy9YF5YG9i1gJ2gIYAmA9gHYA24sZBAttAFywBEAztKACoCWoF0FtjyFSlag1AALEkWYAKAJRoAfDQCudAEbRcwAL6wAPpmH5i5KjXpNWAc04A5G0JzmxVyTLmx5tBswsAIwATADMLMqoasHhQvogwBAwsABK0GzqFKBopjgA2ig8ZAjIsARsCPks-oIAunXM8NVesix1BsAA9F2wyXDpmdm5WD044xzcfAIKUWpkmjq4ANzdveOwDqDOAb61gaERc6yHLKtj%20kA)